# How to plot function(x,y) with y set at specific values in R?

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I am trying to produce a plot like this one: [ggpredict plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1vWE.png) with a function of x and y, NOT a regression equation using a data set. I want the x value to be along the x-axis and the y value to be set at 3 different values, creating three different slopes (like the "group" variable in the picture example).

The picture included is from [this cite](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html) and was created with ggpredict function. After trying to play around with that function, I don't think it will work with the equation approach I am trying to take (seems to be built specifically for regression models)...

Here is the equation I am using:

```
Ae <- 1.57
Ap <- 1.66
Aa <- 2.04
Be <- -1.05
Bp <- 0.39
Ba <- 1.69
Oe <- 1.82
Op <- 1.93
Oa <- 1.19

func <- function(x,y){-0.26 + 0.41*Ae + 0*Ap + 0*Aa + 0.42*(x) + -0.02*(y) + -0.10*Ba + 0.03*Oe + 0.06*Op +
  0*Oa + 0.05*Ae*(x) + 0.03*Ae*Op + 0*Ap*(y) + 0*Aa*Ba + 0.12*(x)*Oe + -0.05*(x)*Op +
  -0.05*(y)*Oe + 0*(y)*Op + 0.03*Ae*(x)*Oe + -.02*Ae*(x)*(y)}
```

I am just trying to explore when y is set at different values how it changes the slope (or impact) of the x variable. I am not sure what to search for to find a function that can help me do this with a function(x,y) equation. Anyone have ideas?

I tried to run the ggpredict code with the function input:

```
func <- function(x,y){-0.26 + 0.41*Ae + 0*Ap + 0*Aa + 0.42*(x) + -0.02*(y) + -0.10*Ba + 0.03*Oe + 0.06*Op +
  0*Oa + 0.05*Ae*(x) + 0.03*Ae*Op + 0*Ap*(y) + 0*Aa*Ba + 0.12*(x)*Oe + -0.05*(x)*Op +
  -0.05*(y)*Oe + 0*(y)*Op + 0.03*Ae*(x)*Oe + -.02*Ae*(x)*(y)}
summary(func)
data_prop <- ggpredict(func, c("x", "y[-1, 0, 1]"))
```

But it produces this error:

> `x` was not found in model terms. Maybe misspelled?
> `y` was not found in model terms. Maybe misspelled?
> Error in !is.null(model_info) && model_info$is_trial :
> invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
> there is no package called ‘RcppAnnoy’
> 2: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
> there is no package called ‘RcppAnnoy’
> 3: Could not access model information.
> 4: Could not get model data.
> 5: Could not access model information.